# google/volley App crashing when URL do not exist

Tags: android, android-volley

So I've implemented google/volley in my apps. When i code the apps i accidentally mistyped the url address and the app just crash suddenly. So how can i avoid this kind of problem. Below are the code i've used.

```
String url_login = "http://10.0.2.2/test_sstem/public/login";

    //Send Post data and retrieve server respond
    StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, url_login,
            new Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {
                    Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this,"On Response "+response,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    ValidateLogin(response);
                }
            },
            new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    NetworkResponse networkResponse = error.networkResponse;
                    if (networkResponse != null && networkResponse.data != null) {
                        String jsonError = new String(networkResponse.data);
                        String message_response=null;
                        try {
                            JSONObject object = new JSONObject(jsonError);
                            message_response= object.getString("error");
                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                        Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "On Error " + message_response.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        showProgress(false);
                    }
                }
            })
```

I know that it can be fixed by correcting the URL, but what if the URL are not alive and working how do we work around this problem.

Comment: can you post stack?

Comment: @Vyacheslav what do you mean by stack term? i dont really know 

Comment: i mean stack trace at crash moment that is shown in android studio's logcat

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have used bellow method for volley which is work for me.. i have used wrong address but my app does not stop. Use bellow full method..

```
private void doLoginAction() {

    pDialog.show();
    String url_login = "http://10.0.2.2/test_sstem/public/login";


    StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, url_login,
            new Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {
                    //pDialog.dismiss();


                    try {
                        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);
                        JSONArray loginNodes = jsonObject.getJSONArray("ParentNode");
                        for (int i = 0; i < loginNodes.length(); i++) {
                            JSONObject jo = loginNodes.getJSONObject(i);
                            String key1 = jo.getString("key1");
                            String key2 = jo.getString("key2");



                        }
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }


                }
            },
            new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    pDialog.dismiss();
                    try {

                        if (error instanceof TimeoutError ) {
                            //Time out error

                        }else if(error instanceof NoConnectionError){
                            //net work error

                        } else if (error instanceof AuthFailureError) {
                            //error

                        } else if (error instanceof ServerError) {
                            //Erroor
                        } else if (error instanceof NetworkError) {
                            //Error

                        } else if (error instanceof ParseError) {
                           //Error

                        }else{
                            //Error
                        }
                        //End


                    } catch (Exception e) {


                    }

                }
            }) {
        @Override
        protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
            Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();
            params.put("uname", "era@gmail.com");
            params.put("pass", "123456");



            return params;
        }

    };

    RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
    requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
}
```

Comment: dude i try those onErrorResponse block and it did work wonder thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

There can be number of reasons why your app crashes with incorrect url, one could be that the host is un resolvable, you can check the validity of a Url by using the following code:

```
URLUtil.isValidUrl(url)
```

Comment: yes the url was not routed by the laravel api, and it cause the app to crash. but the method you gave more to check whether the url format are correct.